# Convert QStrings to other types

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I want to convert QStrings to different types. I would like to do this as generically and easy as possible without having to write an explicit method for each type.

I thought of using a template function, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void getValueFromString(QString str, T& returnVal)
{
    returnVal = static_cast<T>(str);
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but something like that I would like to have.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: "I want to convert QStrings to different types." In what context? Maybe you want to, maybe you don't: tell us what is the bigger problem you're trying to solve. Motivate your question.

Comment: All I really want to do is in the question. Thats all there is. I have QStrings, I want to convert them to: int, int64_t, quint32, double, QStrings, etc. really any sensible type. I do not want to have a separate function for each type but something that I showed above. How does: "I get QStrings that are read from file and I want to interpret them" add more value to the question?

Comment: Motivation would answer obvious issues like "So, you really want to convert the `QString{"五"}` to `double(5.0)`?" You can't claim that this is not converting a string to a "sensible type" - it obviously is! How do you know *what* type you want to convert to? Etc. Saying "that's all there is", as you claim, is not helpful.

Comment: As a matter of fact, that is exactly what I want to do. If the cast fails, because the QString cannot be converted to double, that is fine, then I will cope with it. The point is I want to have a function that I can use to convert a QString to a type that I specify, and thats also what I wrote in the question. I provided an example of how I imagined that  could happen (template parameter). I find the question concise and the inclusion of information that might or might not be helpful for context, would make it only more convoluted.

Comment: Have you ever looked at `QString` documentation? If so, then you should provide motivation as to why you wish to pass the type as a template parameter to a template method, and not simply as a method name itself, and you should mention why do you consider the api of `QString` deficient. If you didn't read the documentation...

Comment: "If the cast fails, because the QString cannot be converted to double" Whether the "cast" fails or not is completely up to how you implement it! Do you need a way to convert Japanese numerals to their numeric type representation or not? And so on. You provide zero requirements, and the question is left open to wide interpretation because of it. What's obvious to you stems from your requirements, we can't divine them.

Comment: I know the QString API. I also do not say that it is deficient. My only requirement is that I have a single function with which I can control the conversion instead of having a function for each type. I do not need a reason for that, I just want to know how I can do that.  You are over engineering the problem immensly. I did get answers I am content with. If I saw that the answers all deviate in the wrong direction I would agree that the question needs more context, but somehow people understood what I meant. Think of occam's razor man.

Comment: If a function takes explicit (non-deducted) template arguments, then it's no different in its use than having multiple functions. The explicit argument is essentially a part of the function's name. So your "requirement" to have a single function is not possible unless you somehow have the type available for deduction. And in that case you shouldn't use a function, just use a `QTextStream` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use stream:

```
template<typename T>
void getValueFromString(QString str, T& returnVal)
{
    QTextStream stream(str);
    stream >> returnVal;
}
```

Comment: This works, but given the plethora of `QString` methods that do the conversion and return the desired type, it is absurdly costly. It solves an imaginary problem that is already solved anyway.

Answer (score 4):

[QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) has lots of convert methods and you probably don't need your new function, for example:

```
QString str = "FF";
bool ok;
int hex = str.toInt(&ok, 16);       // hex == 255, ok == true
int dec = str.toInt(&ok, 10);       // dec == 0, ok == false
```

I'm not sure it's OK to inherit from `QString` or not, but you can make a child from it and override casts. You can override cast of a class, for example:

```
class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(int radius) : radius(radius) {}
    operator int() const { return radius; } 
private:
    int radius;
};

int x = static_cast<int>(aCircle);
```

Again, overriding `static_cast` for `QString` doesn't look logical.

Comment: In this case I need to go through each of the conversion functions. I would like to avoid that. Also there might be cases where two conversion methods of QStrings actually work ("200" can be casted to int and to double for example). Also I would like to allow cast to string. Sounds silly? It is. Its a design decision I have to live with. I am just trying to make my life a bit easier.

Comment: @FreddyKay: Then Jarod42's solution fits your requirement.

Comment: True. I just wanted to point out, why, though your decision would work for above question, I personally cannot use it.

Comment: Type conversion operators should be used *very* judiciously. The suggestion that enabling a string-derived type to be castable to numerical types is very misguided.

Comment: @KubaOber: Yes, this just tries to answer the question at the first place. However I agree with you and this is what I've written in the answer to avoid overriding these kind of conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally you may use [Qt's meta-object system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE), which works well with custom types.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
    ...
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)

...

MyStruct s;
QVariant var;
var.setValue(s); // copy s into the variant

...

// retrieve the value
MyStruct s2 = var.value<MyStruct>();
```

Note that a `QVariant` can easily be converted into a `QString`.

---

Some more detailed reading is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html).

Comment: I will keep it in mind for the future. Seems a bit of an overkill for my current problem, as I only work with primitive types. Still, this is a nice addition.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point but it comes in handy if you need the `QVariant` conversion to stay in touch with some widget classes. Glad I could show you a thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If Boost is an option you could write:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template<typename T>
void getValueFromString(QString str, T& returnVal)
{
  returnVal = boost::lexical_cast<T>(str.toStdString());
}
```

References:

- [`toStdString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString)
- Boost [`lexical_cast<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Comment: Didn't even think of it, but unfortunately boost is not possible.